# Почему то дублируется элементы

Tags: php

Есть 2 массива: $adminGenred, где хранатся жанры фильмов и $rowsG, где хранятся жанры у конкретного фильма.Я их хочу перебрать массив и сравнить если у этого фильма есть жанры боевик, то input должен быть checked, иначе простой инпут.
Я написал

```
            foreach ($adminGenred as $genre) {
            $g = 0;
            echo '<div class="genre-name">';

            if (count($rowsG) != 0) {

                foreach ($rowsG as $rowG) {
                    $g++;
                    if ($genre['id'] == $rowG['id']) {
                        $g++;
                        echo '<input checked class="option-input checkbox" type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="' . $genre['id'] . '">';
                        echo '<span class="text"> ' . $genre['genre'] . '</span>.';
                    } else {
                        if ($g <= 1) {
                            echo '<input class="option-input checkbox" type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="' . $genre['id'] . '">';
                            echo '<span class="text"> ' . $genre['genre'] . '</span>.';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
```

получилось вот это, если этот жанр есть в фильме то ставиться и checked и простой input
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался выцепить это дело как-то счетчиком, не получилось. Не могу понять данное поведение. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема в логике вашего кода.

Comment: В чем именно, я и не могу найти эту логическую проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу проблему можно решить например так:

```
foreach ($adminGenred as $genre) {
    echo '<div class="genre-name">';

    // вводим флажок        
    $isSelected = false;

    if (count($rowsG) != 0) {
        foreach ($rowsG as $rowG) {
            if ($genre['id'] == $rowG['id']) {
                echo '<input checked class="option-input checkbox" type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="' . $genre['id'] . '">';
                echo '<span class="text"> ' . $genre['genre'] . '</span>.';

                // Отмечаем что данный жанр выбран
                $isSelected = true;
                // Выходим из цикла так как понятно что жанр выбран
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Флажок говорит что жанр НЕ выбран - нарисуем неотмеченный чекбокс
    if (!$isSelected) {
        echo '<input class="option-input checkbox" type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="' . $genre['id'] . '">';
        echo '<span class="text"> ' . $genre['genre'] . '</span>.';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Также данный код можно упростить и выводить чекбокс только в одном месте с учетом флажка `$isSelected`.

Comment: Ну собственно как я предложил в ответе выше. Каноничней получается

Answer (score -1):

Всё очень просто, у вас кривой алгоритм. Допустим ситуацию
1. У нас жанры: боевик, детектив. А у фильма жанр детектив, боевик.
2. Перебираем жанр => боевик. Фильм => детектив. Ставим не выбранный боевик
3. Перебираем жанр => боевик. Фильм => боевик. Ставим выбранный боевик

Второй цикл у вас должен только говорить выбрана позиция или нет (причём можно не перебирать дальше, если нашли совпадение).
 Первый цикл должен строить флажки